# How to make full height my Flatlist Item in react native?

Tags: react-native

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

I have 5 items in FlatList.

I want my items render evenly in fullscreen(Top image to Bottom image).

If I change height or flex, It will shows 5 items in current backgroundImage space.

what should I change..?

```
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'column',
            backgroundColor: 'black',
          }}
        >
          <FlatList
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            data={emotions}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <ImageBackground
                source={item.img}
                style={{
                  width: '100%',
                  height: '100%',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  margin: 2,
                  alignContent: 'stretch',
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 20,
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    color: 'white',
                  }}
                  onPress={() => this.handlePress(`${item.title}`)}
                >
                  {item.title}
                </Text>
              </ImageBackground>
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.title}
            numColumns={1}
          ></FlatList>
        </View>
```

Comment: Kinda vague but did you want to center the text? the Flatlist seems to be rendered evenly already?

Comment: @keysl yes!! I want make text in center So I changed

Answer (score 0):

**In render item can you try this**

**Please replace this**

```
height: '100%'
```

**with**

```
flex:1
```

Comment: I set flex:1 in renderItem that is what I said in question.
5 items in current backgroundImage space.